# Collection of objects with different interface

Tags: c++, oop, collections

I'm writing a decision tree based algorithm (ID3). I use two classess to represent a node. ResultNode, and TestNode. ResultNode is kind of leaf. It simply contains a result with a method to aquire it. TestNode is simply not-leaf. It has an array of children, and test function.
The most basic approach is create more general class Node which would provide interface for both of them, however both test, and getResult are specific to it's classess. Having test function in ResultNode doesn't make any sense, as well as having getResult in TestNode. They should just return any value for opposite classess, and never be used.

```
class Node {
public: //I don't care about encapsulation in this example
   bool is_leaf;
   virtual int getResult() { return 0; } //int because, type isn't important here
   virtual int test() { return 0; }
}
```

Then I must be aware to call only functions appropriate to object type (hence boolean variable). The only thing I can do to protect the code is inserting some ugly macro that throws warnings when original functions are called. But all this pattern look very ugly in my opinion.

Of course I can also move those functions to desired subclassess, but as all pointers are Node type I would need to use casting in order to call those methods, which is way more uglier. (even my supervisor says so)
Now I wonder, whether it would be any better if I had used a function that returns a reference of given type:

```
TestNode& getTestNode() {
    return *nodePointer;
}
```

I am almost sure that there is a design pattern that use such technique, but I looks like a nasty hack to me.

**Edit**:
After some research I found out that you can deal with casting problem from my second approach using a `Visitor` or `Command` design pattern.

Comment: How about multiple collections, one for each kind of node?

Comment: @rightfold Overcomplicated and it would affect tree-structure too much. Moreover the leaves are very rare so keeping special collection object just to be empty all the time seems quite expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In actual use it seems that the concept of a `TestNode` is that it ultimately allows getting a `ResultNode` - so Node can have a `getResult` method that for a `TestNode` walks down the tree and for a `ResultNode` returns `this` -- the `test` method is likely a private method of `TestNode` that is used to find the `ResultNode`.

Something like:

```
class ResultNode;

class Node
{
public:
    virtual ResultNode * getResult() = 0;
};

class TestNode : public Node
{
public:
   virtual ResultNode * getResult() {
          /* does things to find next TestNode or ResultNode */
          return found->getResult();
   }
private:
    test() { ... }
    Node * children;  // dynamic array of Nodes (TestNode or ResultNode) 
};

class ResultNode : public node
{
   virtual ResultNode * getResult() { return this; }
}
```

Comment: In my concept the `test` was such function although it was returning the proper index in the table of children. Your approach is more object oriented and I like it, however you have missed one thing. To walk down the tree the return value must be of type `Node` because `TestNode` isn't `ResultNode`. Then I'd still need the cast to `ResultNode` in order to see it's result field.

Comment: @pkubik ResultNode is fine as a return - the `getResult` will never return until it finds a ResultNode - it uses recursion in `TestNodes` so it never returns a `TestNode`